# Which problem is the Diamond Problem exactly?

Tags: language-agnostic, diamond-problem

I see at least 2 separate problems related to the diamond class hierarchy (note the example code below is in C++ but I believe my question is language-agnostic):

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void f()
    {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }
};

class D : public B, public C
{
};

D d;
d.f();
```

Problem 1: Do `B` and `C` share one common instance of `A` or do they both have a separate instance? (Yes, I know how it's resolved in C++ but the general problem remains.)

Problem 2: Call to `d.f()` is ambiguous.

My question is - when people talk about the Diamond Problem which problem do they actually mean? 1 or 2? Or possibly both?

Answer (score 0):

Says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem):

> The "diamond problem" (sometimes referred to as the "Deadly Diamond of Death"[6]) is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If there is a method in A that B and C have overridden, and D does not override it, then which version of the method does D inherit: that of B, or that of C?

That's your "problem 2".

Comment: The very same Wiki page then states: "Mitigation
Languages have different ways of dealing with these problems of repeated inheritance.
- C++ by default follows each inheritance path separately, so a D object would actually contain two separate A objects" So Wiki actually mentions (and seems to confuse) both problems. I don't trust Wiki with this.

Comment: OK, but Wikipedia doesn't say that the second issue (i.e. your "problem 1") *is* the "diamond problem".

Answer (score 0):

When people talk about the diamond problem, they usually don't distinguish between these two problems.  But sometimes they do, especially if they're explaining a mitigating feature of some particular language.

"Diamond problem" is a colloquial expression that doesn't have a universally accepted *formal* definition.  You can interpret it as "the problem of multiple inheritance nets"... for which there are various solutions.

Comment: So is it fair to say that the Diamond Problem is a group of problems?

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't.  I think of the ambiguous base class instance, the ambiguous method implementation, and the ambiguous field, as exactly the same problem.  We're just talking about different parts of the duplicated base.

Comment: No, ambiguous method comes from B and C having their own overrides (while D doesn't), not from the duplicated base.